# How to update a key value in JSON dynamically?

Tags: json, groovy

I have a JSON like below

```
{
"context":{
    "parameters":[
    {
        "name":"stub",``
        "value": {"item value":"abcdefg"}
    },  
    {
        "name":"category",
        "value":{"item value":"cars"}
    },
    {
        "name":"year",
        "value":{"item value":"2012"}
    },
    {
        "name":"make",
        "value":{"item value":"toyota"}
    },
    {   
        "name":"cars",
        "value":{"item value":"corolla"}
    }
]
}
```

I am supplied with a two strings dynamically like "cars" and "accord". I need to search for "cars" and then replace the "item value" under it  to "accord". I have tried to convert it to map but have no success.

Any suggestions about how I can achieve this?

Comment: What language are you doing this in

Comment: JSON is just structured data. What programming language are you using to manipulate it?

Comment: I am trying to do this using groovy in soapui

Comment: please update the question with this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it in Groovy.

Assuming that the JSON is like so (I have corrected it; there are illegal chars in the original question):

```
def s = '''
{
"context":{
    "parameters":[
    {
        "name":"stub",
        "value": {"item value":"abcdefg"}
    },  
    {
        "name":"category",
        "value":{"item value":"cars"}
    },
    {
        "name":"year",
        "value":{"item value":"2012"}
    },
    {
        "name":"make",
        "value":{"item value":"toyota"}
    },
    {   
        "name":"cars",
        "value":{"item value":"corolla"}
    }
    ]
    }
}
'''
```

then consider:

```
import groovy.json.*

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(s)
def category = jsonSlurper.context.parameters.find { it.name == "cars" }
category.value."item value" = "accord"
println new JsonBuilder(jsonSlurper).toPrettyString()
```

Comment: Thank you very much that solves it.. I was messing it up with making it a map then loop into it.

Comment: Is this pass by reference?
I am able to find the element and edit as well. But it is not updating the actual JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with `javascript`. If you are working with JSON format you can parse that data to an object.

```
const data = JSON.parse("your json data")

data.context.parameters.map(param => {
  if ( param.name !== "cars") {
   return param
  }
  return  {
    "name": "cars",
    value: {"accord": "corolla"}
  }
})
```